# reinterpret_cast used in multi inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, reinterpret-cast

During doing some c++ excercises I found an interesting example related to multi inheritance and casting.

I cannot figure out why 
`reinterpret_cast<char*>(b1) is not equal reinterpret_cast<char*>(b2)`.

Here is a simple program, I mentioned above:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() : m_i(0) { }

protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() : m_d(0.0) { }

protected:
    double m_d;
};

class C
    : public A
    , public B
{
public:
    C() : m_c('a') { }

private:
    char m_c;
};

int main()
{
    C d;
    A *b1 = &d;
    B *b2 = &d;

    const int a = (reinterpret_cast<char*>(b1) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d)) ? 1 : 2;
    const int b = (b2 == &d) ? 3 : 4;
    const int c = (reinterpret_cast<char*>(b1) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(b2)) ? 5 : 6;

    std::cout << a << b << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Could you provide any comments to this topis to help me to figure out why reinterpret_cast(b1) is not equal reinterpret_cast(b2), when reinterpret_cast(b1) equals reinterpret_cast(&d)?

Comment: Change the order in which you inherit A and B, and examine the results. Does that help you understand what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base class subobjects have to be somehow arranged in memory inside the most derived object. In your case, it seems the compiler did this:

```
C---------------+
|A---+ B---+    |
||m_i| |m_d| m_c|
|+---+ +---+    |
+---------------+
```

Which means the `A` subobject starts at the same address as the entire `C` object, but the `B` subobject is shifted by the size of `A` (i.e. the size of an `int`).

```
B *b2 = &d;
```

Because `b2` is a pointer to `B`, it points to the `B` subobject, thus the physical address it points to is the shifted one.

As for why `b2 == &d` holds - pointers to different types can never be compared for equality. But a pointer to derived class can be implicitly converted to a pointer to base class. So `b2 == &d` is actually converted to `b2 == static_cast<B*>(&d)`, which holds. Note that the implicit conversion naturally applies the shift, and it's the same one you used to obtain `b2` in the first place.

You can experiment with reorganising the inheritance order or removing/adding some data members to see how it affects layout.

Comment: Ok, this sounds reasonable, but if so
why b2 == &d is TRUE
but reinterpret_cast<char*>(b2) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d) is FALSE then?

Comment: @Leopoldo: Because your assumptions are false ;) Specifically, `b2 == &d` is not `(void*)b2 == (void*)&d` but instead it *converts* `&d` to `B*`, which applies the offset, and only then compares as in `b2 == static_cast<B*>(&d)`.

Comment: @Leopoldo I've expanded the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why *should* the addresses be equal? `*b1` is an object of type `A`, and `*b2` is an object of type `B`. They are different objects (albeit not complete ones) and neither one is a subobject of the other, so it's perfectly expected for them to have different addresses -- in fact, they only way they could have the same address is if at least one of their types was empty (which isn't the case in your code).